# Batch file to create Folder based on Date and Copy Files from One Location to Another Location?

Tags: batch-file

I want to Copy/Move files in Windows XP from Desktop(a Folder) to My Document(another Folder), which was created by same Batch File on Current Date in Format DD/MM/YYYY.

This is working fine when .BAT File is in Desktop Folder.

```
@echo off
set date="%date:~7,2%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~10,4%"
mkdir %date%
copy *.txt \%date%
pause
```

Now what this .BAT is doing is, creating Folder 18-01-2013 on Desktop and coping all .TXT files in this Folder.

But this is not working,

```
@echo off
set date="%date:~7,2%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~10,4%"
mkdir %USERPROFILE%\My Documents\%date%
copy %USERPROFILE%\desktop\*.txt %USERPROFILE%\My Documents\%date%
pause
```

This .BAT File is creating these folders;
1. In C Drive>Documents
2. On Desktop (and, Chandel>My, Documents>18-01-2013, Settings>Anshuman)

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try putting lines that has file/folder names with spaces in quotes e.g. update this line

```
mkdir %USERPROFILE%\My Documents\%date%
```

to

```
mkdir "%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\%date%"
```